# Firebase Cloud Functions and FFMPEG - Cannot find module 'fluent-ffmpeg'

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to use Ffmpeg in a firebase cloud function, but can't seem to deploy it, as I get a deploy error of **Cannot find module 'fluent-ffmpeg'**

[image]

This is what my project structure looks like

[image]

the package.json under the functions directory looks like this

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.61.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and in the outer package.json I have this declared

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/storage-types": "^0.8.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^6.11.0",
    "@types/fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.21",
    "ffmpeg": "^0.0.4",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^5.1.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

I have downloaded the static binaries for Ffmpeg and have it in the ffmpeg folder like this

[image]

My index.ts looks like this where I declare the dependency

```
import * as ffmpeg from "fluent-ffmpeg";

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(path.join(__dirname, "./ffmpeg/ffmpeg"));
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(path.join(__dirname, "./ffmpeg/ffprobe"));
```

I've been banging my head on this for the past week, trawled all the current answers around this sort of area to no avail.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For those that ever come across this issue, it was just me being an idot lol.

I was installing the npm dependencies in the root of my project, as opposed to in the functions directory.

Once I installed from there, problems went all away, and I didn't need to include the static binaries either.

Comment: If you have a solution to your problem, please either delete the question or answer it yourself and accept the answer as correct.  Don't leave your resolution as a comment.

Comment: thanks @DougStevenson but I can't accept my own answer until after 48 hours then I'll mark it answered.

Comment: I don't see a single answer showing here yet, just comments.